# How to use classify to separate lines and circles

Tags: data, machine-learning

I generated lines and circles:

```
lines = Table[
   Graphics[
    Line[{{RandomInteger[{0, 10}], 
       RandomInteger[{0, 10}]}, {RandomInteger[{0, 10}], 
       RandomInteger[{0, 10}]}}], ImageSize -> 10], {x, 1, 20}];
circles = 
  Table[Graphics[
    Circle[{RandomInteger[{0, 10}], RandomInteger[{0, 10}]}, 
     RandomInteger[{0, 20}]], ImageSize -> 10], {x, 1, 20}];
```

and put them into a classifier

```
c = Classify[{lines -> "lines", circles -> "circles"}]
```

the training was successful with no errors, but when trying to test the classifier with:

```
test = Graphics[Line[{{0, 1}, {0, 2}}], ImageSize -> 10]
c[test]
```

I get the error:

> ClassifierFunction::mlbddataev: The data being evaluated is not
> formatted correctly.

And I do not understand what the problem is. Can somebody tell me, how to correctly format the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the way I would do it.

- Data needs to be `Association`, not  list, when you label by the whole batches and not single objects.
- A good training set has varying data, not almost identical. Hence, carefully design `Graphics` so circles and lines are different sizes and in different places. You can also add noise (like random points), but I did not do it for simplicity.
- Experiment with larger training sets to see improvement of accuracy.
- `PerformanceGoal->"Quality"` is recommended for more accurate results.
- This case works out well with `Graphics` but in more complex cases you can always consider converting `Graphics` to `Image` with `Rasterize` and using [Neural Networks](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/).

Training set:

```
lines = ParallelTable[Graphics[{Thick,Line[RandomReal[10,{2,2}]]}, 
ImageSize -> 50,PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,10}}], {x, 1, 100}];

circles = ParallelTable[Graphics[{Thick,Circle[RandomReal[{3,7},2], RandomReal[{1,3}]]},
ImageSize -> 50,PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,10}}], {x, 1, 100}];
```

Here is a sample (frames are only to stress varying locations of lines and circles within the `Graphics`):

```
Framed /@ RandomSample[lines~Join~circles, 10]
```

[image]

Train:

```
c=Classify[<|"lines"->lines,"circles"->circles|>,PerformanceGoal->"Quality"]

Information[c]
```

[image]

Test set:

```
linesTEST=ParallelTable[Graphics[{Thick,Line[RandomReal[10,{2,2}]]}, 
ImageSize -> 100,PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,10}}], {x, 1, 20}];

circlesTEST = ParallelTable[Graphics[{Thick,Circle[RandomReal[{3,7},2], RandomReal[{1,3}]]},
ImageSize -> 50,PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,10}}], {x, 1, 20}];
```

Measure performance:

```
cm=ClassifierMeasurements[c,<|"lines"->linesTEST,"circles"->circlesTEST|>]

cm["ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

[image]

Comment: `c = Classify[<|"lines" -> lines, "circles" -> circles|>, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]` does not work for me, outputting "ClassifierFunction[Input type: Image
Classes: circles,lines


Data not in notebook; Store now ».

]".

Comment: @user64494 it is not an error.

Comment: @Vtaliy Kaurov: You wrote "it is not an error". However, after that the rest of your code does not work for me in 12.1.1.0 on Windows 10, resultng in "ClassifierMeasurementsObject[Classifier: LogisticRegression
Number of test examples: 40


Data not in notebook; Store now »

]".

Comment: @user64494 - not sure, works for me on 12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 9, 2020)

Comment: Works for me in 12.1.1.0 on Windows 10. I also get "Data not in notebook; Store now" in the `ClassifierFunction` and that's not an error. Get the same results as the answer. @user64494

Comment: @anderstood thank you for testing and verifying :-)

Comment: @anderstood: Indeed, on a fresh kernel `cm["ConfusionMatrixPlot"]` builds a plot.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the use of Associations in this case. But it works well for me!